# Как сделать цветные линии и маркеры в функции ezplot?

Tags: matlab

Вот код но мне нужно чтобы были цветные линии на графике как это сделать?

```
explot ('2*x^3 - 3*x^2 + 5', [-5 5])
hold on
explot ('x^3/(x^2-1)', [0 3])
axis tight
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `ezplot` возвращает объект типа `Line`, представляющий нарисованный график. Если у этого объекта поменять свойство `Color`, цвет линии поменяется:

```
h1= ezplot ('2*x^3 - 3*x^2 + 5', [-5 5]);
h1.Color= 'Green';
hold on
h2= ezplot ('x^3/(x^2-1)', [0 3]);
h2.Color= [0.3 0.2 0.5];
```